# Shared dependency references

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, abstraction

I have an `IClientConnection` interface in my domain layer that takes care of connecting to an IRC Server. I was wanting to hide the communication with the server behind a service layer.

#### The Service interfaces

I created a couple of service interfaces. `IIrcConnectionService` provides two methods, `ConnectToServer` and `Disconnect`. It handles talking to the `IClientConnection` implementation. The second service interface is `IChannelService` and provides two methods, `JoinChannel` and `PartChannel`.

```
public class IrcConnectionService : IIrcConnectionService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The client connection
    /// </summary>
    private IClientConnection clientConnection;

    /// <summary>
    /// The connected completed callback
    /// </summary>
    private Action connectedCompletedCallback;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IrcConnectionService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientConnection">The client connection.</param>
    public IrcConnectionService(IClientConnection clientConnection)
    {
        this.clientConnection = clientConnection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects to server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverInfo">The server information.</param>
    /// <param name="userInfo">The user information.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    public Task ConnectToServer(ServerConnectionInfo serverInfo, UserInformation userInfo, Action connectedCompletedCallback = null)
    {
        if (connectedCompletedCallback != null)
        {
            this.connectedCompletedCallback = connectedCompletedCallback;
            this.clientConnection.Connected += this.OnClientConnected;
        }

        IrcConnectionService.CacheConnection(this.clientConnection);
        return this.clientConnection.Connect(serverInfo, userInfo);
    }

    private void OnClientConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.connectedCompletedCallback();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects from server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverInfo">The server information.</param>
    public void DisconnectFromServer(ServerConnectionInfo serverInfo)
    {
        this.clientConnection.Connected -= this.OnClientConnected;
        this.clientConnection.Disconnect();
    }
}

public class ChannelService : IChannelService
{
    private IIrcConnectionService connectionService;

    private IClientConnection connection;

    public ChannelService(IIrcConnectionService connectionService)
    {
        this.connectionService = connectionService;
    }

    public Task JoinChannel(string server, string channelName, string password = "")
    {
        if (!this.connectionService.IsConnected)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You must connect to a server prior to joining a channel.");
        }

        if (!channelName.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            channelName = channelName.Insert(0, "#");
        }

        return this.connectionService.SendMessage($"JOIN {channelName}");
    }

    public Task PartChannel(string serverNaemstring channelName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The application can connect to more than one server. So the dependency injection container (Unity) does not register them as a singleton. Instead, it creates a new instance each time one is needed.

The trouble here now becomes sharing the `IClientConnection` instance across multiple instantiations of the same service, or different services as needed. For example, my view model below uses an instance of `IIrcConnectionService` to connect to the server, then uses `IChannelService` to join a channel. When the call to `JoinChannel` happens, the service has a null `IClientConnection` because I don't know what route I should take in order to provide it the same reference shared by the `IIrcConnectionService` that owns the connection.

```
public class ShellViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The irc connection service
    /// </summary>
    private IIrcConnectionService ircConnectionService;

    /// <summary>
    /// The channel service
    /// </summary>
    private IChannelService channelService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ShellViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionService">The connection service.</param>
    public ShellViewModel(IIrcConnectionService connectionService, IChannelService channelService)
    {
        this.ircConnectionService = connectionService;
        this.channelService = channelService;

        this.InitializeCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(this.Initialize);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the initialize command.
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand InitializeCommand { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        var serverInfo = new ServerConnectionInfo { Url = "chat.freenode.net" };
        var userInfo = new UserInformation { PrimaryNickname = "DevTestUser" };

        // Connect to the server
        await this.ircConnectionService.ConnectToServer(
            serverInfo,
            userInfo,
            async () => await this.channelService.JoinChannel("#ModernIrc"));
    }
}
```

One of the things I was thinking about was building an internal `ConnectionCache` object. The `IIrcConnectionService` implementation would push its `IClientConnection` reference in to it, by Server name. The `IChannelService` would request an `IClientConnection` by Server name from the `ConnectionCache` object.

Does this sound like a valid path? Are there patterns I can look at to solve this differently? Any guidance on this would be appreciated.